# How to remove drag start animation from react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: animation, flicker, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to create a "palette" to drag from using `react-beautiful-dnd`. This will be like a palette in a drawing app, ie. (a copy of) the draggable will remain in the palette during the drag, and the palette will not animate at drag start or drag end.

I have achieved most of what I require using:

1. setting `isDropEnabled={true}`
2. hiding the placeholder with CSS `div[data-rbd-placeholder-context-id] {display: none !important;}`
3. reducing the drop animation according to https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/drop-animation.md
4. reducing the drag animation with CSS `div[data-rbd-draggable-context-id] {transition: 0.001s !important;}`
5. inserting a duplicate `Draggable` in `onDragStart`

There is still a flicker on dragging, and a flicker on dropping.

Is there anything else I can do to prevent `react-beautiful-dnd` from animating the removal of the draggable at drag start, and also at drag end?

[image]